# SOAP envelope response not determined by client

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am developing a location web-service in PHP. The wsdl and messaging structure is complete however I am having an issue with Response messages. For some soap clients the result is not displayed. Can someone tell what is the issue with this message?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
               xmlns:ns="http://asimishaq.com/wsdl/TestServices/IPLocation"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns:getCountryNameByIpResponse>
         <ns:result>Chicago, IL, UNITED STATES (US)</ns:result>
      </ns:getCountryNameByIpResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The wsdl for the service is at the following location:

http://asimishaq.com/wsdl/TestServices/IPLocation?wsdl

Answer (score 0):

I check your WSDL and I notice missing this definition:

```
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
```

This definition I use for all wsdl tags. For example:

```
<wsdl:definitions (...) >
  <wsdl:types>
   <xs:schema (...)

 </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message (...)
```

But it is not solve your problem.

> For some soap clients the result is not displayed.

I think the response is correct. May be have problem with call this web service. If one soap clients it works you can compare this code with that client code which it doesn't work. If it possible please log this request and you test this request with [soapUi](http://www.soapui.org/) or another test client.

Can you share soap client which result not display?